# Python "for" inside "any" syntax error?

Tags: python, for-loop, syntax, any, python-2.2

I have a piece of code that broke the other day and I can't find the problem. I need to do something if I find a coincidence between a user input and the first value of any element of a list of lists.
I had this code running in another computer, but somehow I can't make it run anymore:

```
if any(orderinput == x[0] for x in order):
```

`orderinput` is the user input and `order` is the list of lists. This worked once and should be working based on what I've read here on stackoverflow, but it throws a syntax error at the `r` in `for`.

I tried moving it between lines or adding spaces, but the error follows the `r`.

I'm working in Python 2.2. I don't remember the version in the machine I made the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generator expressions are available since python 2.4. Try changing to a list comprehension:

```
if any([orderinput == x[0] for x in order]):
```

Python 2.2 is twelve years old. *A lot* of things were different.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the problem. I think the other computer has python 2.4 now that you mention it. Thanks again.